# SSLError: [SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, pygsheets

I have a python script which runs quite well on the windows server but throws an SSLError exception when running on Ubuntu 16.04.5.

I have used `pygsheets`to connect to the google sheet.

```
import pygsheets
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = [
        'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
         ]

credentials01 = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds01.json', scope)
credentials02 = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds02.json', scope)

file01 = pygsheets.authorize(credentials=credentials01)
file02 = pygsheets.authorize(credentials=credentials02)
wb01 = file01.open('Database System 2')
wb02 = file02.open('Database System 2')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    output_dfs = manager.list()
    new_dfs_dict = manager.dict()
    for l in main_list:
        for i in range(0, len(l[0]), 5):
            processes = []
            ids_sublist = []
            for j in range(i, i + 5):
                try:
                    ids_sublist.append(l[0][j])
                except:
                    pass
            for ID in ids_sublist:
                processes.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=fetch_data, args=(ID, start_date, end_date, new_dfs_dict, output_dfs)))
            for p in processes:
                p.start()
            for p in processes:
                p.join()

        for ID in l[0]:
            if not l[1].empty:
                cols_list = list(l[2][ID].columns)
                cols_list.remove('Type')
                cols_list[1:1] = ['Type']
                l[2][ID] = l[2][ID][cols_list]
                l[2][ID].update(new_dfs_dict[ID])
                l[2][ID] = pd.merge(l[2][ID], new_dfs_dict[ID])
            else:
                l[2][ID] = new_dfs_dict[ID]
        ready_to_set_df = pd.DataFrame()
        for ID in l[2]:
            ready_to_set_df = pd.concat([ready_to_set_df, l[2][ID]], sort=False)
            output_sheet = wb01.worksheet_by_title(l[3])            
            output_sheet.clear()
            output_sheet.set_dataframe(ready_to_set_df.fillna(0), 'A1')

    output_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=bank_portal_data_header)
    for df in output_dfs:
        output_df = output_df.append(df)
    try:
        data_sheet = wb02.worksheet_by_title(end_date)
        data_df = data_sheet.get_as_df(has_header=True)
        output_df = data_df[bank_portal_data_header].append(output_df)
        output_df = output_df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
        data_sheet.clear()
        data_sheet.set_dataframe(output_df, 'A1', copy_head=True)
    except:
        data_sheet = wb02.add_worksheet(end_date)
        data_sheet.set_dataframe(output_df, 'A1', copy_head=True)
```

It throws the SSLError at `data_sheet.clear()`

The strange part is the script runs wonderfully on the Windows Server. Thanks

Comment: Did you get an answer to this? I'm having a very similar error when using a multi-threading approach

Comment: Can you add exception stack trace to the question? @UnknownCoder

Answer (score 3):

I would try to update the `ca-certificates`.  This information is taken from [Adding CAcert root certificate to Debian/Ubuntu](https://www.brightbox.com/blog/2014/03/04/add-cacert-ubuntu-debian/):

```
# first make a directory in which to store the CAcert certificate files.
sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cacert.org 
# Download the root certificates from the --> http://www.cacert.org
sudo wget -P /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cacert.org http://www.cacert.org/certs/root.crt http://www.cacert.org/certs/class3.crt
# update certificate bundle
sudo update-ca-certificates
```